# Splitting line with equal parts in range

Tags: qgis, line, splitting

How to split line into equal parts in QGIS, with a certain condition: the parts to be between `50m` to `150m`?

Comment: Why is this on hold?  It is perfectly clear what is being asked - OP wants to split a line into equal parts.

Comment: It is not clear currently, how the length of the parts should be determined. If there is a precondition, it should be described more thoroughly IMO.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Split Lines by Maximum Length` in the `Processing Toolbox`.

An alternative would be to use the `QChainage` plugin - this will give you a set of points at specified distances along the line.  You can then use the points to split the lines with the `Saga Split lines with points` tool... but that's really a two step equivalent of the above!

With both approaches, while you can control the maximum distance, it is difficult to control the minimum because the algorithm will follow the line and you will get a portion of line left over at the end. If very short lengths are not acceptable, you could use method #1 and instead of a fixed length, supply a formula that accounts for the length of the line - divide the line length by your target subdivision length.  Round (floor or ceiling) the result and set the length to the rounded result.  The expression can be set using the little button to the right of the "maximum line length entry box.  This way you can avoid very short length.  It depends on your use-case.